Getting [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address while making a query with llama engine
I'm building Telegram bot with ai using llama-index library, ollama and docker-compose.
It works without docker-compose, but if i run it in docker, i get [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address (i guess from ollama) in my bot script.
I'm getting index with this method:
def get_index():
    ollama_embedding = OllamaEmbedding(
        model_name="llama3",
        base_url="http://kargenia-ollama:11434",
        ollama_additional_kwargs={"mirostat": 0},
    )

    Settings.embed_model = ollama_embedding
    Settings.llm = Ollama(model="llama3", request_timeout=300.0)
    if os.path.exists('./index_dir/docstore.json'):
        print('exists')
        storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir='index_dir')
        index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
        return index
    else:
        print('new')
        storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults()
        documents = load_documents()
        index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
            documents, storage_context=storage_context
        )
        storage_context.persist(persist_dir='./index_dir')
        return index

and use it to make my queries, here is my query method
index = get_index() # getting the index

def query(query_text: str) -> str:
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
    response = query_engine.query(query_text)
    return response

on the line query_engine.query(query_text), I get the error 99 that i mentioned above.
Here's my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'

services:
  ollama:
    image: ollama/ollama
    container_name: kargenia-ollama
    ports:
      - "11434:11434"
    volumes:
      - ollama:/root/.ollama
      - ./ollama/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh" ]
    networks:
      - llama-network
  bot:
    container_name: kargenia-bot
    build:
      context: ./bot
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./bot/entrypoint.sh:/app/entrypoint.sh
      - ./bot/index_dir:/app/index_dir
    networks:
      - llama-network
volumes:
  ollama:
networks:
  llama-network:
    driver: bridge

and docker file for bot service
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/entrypoint.sh" ]

This works without docker successfully and I get a response with query_engine.query(query_text)
Initially, I thought that my bot service doesn't have access to ollama service. I got into interactive mode, I've sent get request with curl and it was successful, so bot has an access to ollama.
Even if I run bot script without docker and ollama in docker, it'll work fine.
If I run: docker network inspect kargenia_bot_llama-network
[
    {
        "Name": "kargenia_bot_llama-network",
        "Id": "72eb089cc86a0b5a5cc24eaf563ef5f033b8a093c0ae69050cfae5975adcf989",
        "Created": "2024-06-11T15:52:34.074973469Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0e22f90f614902ee1873f065bf9c6d04dcd6fc8aba4bb2f6afc6d21cd65872b3": {
                "Name": "kargenia-ollama",
                "EndpointID": "d518b4206897d066efcb55cd5c1fdd7e3537cfc1b04575798743709e566acde4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "0ee8c7118e46fe41a76b8cfe9d131c3d3965271fe1a6b68a1ce94ae7a2d92f65": {
                "Name": "kargenia-bot",
                "EndpointID": "11f3d60c6d82ee9fdc15513454f6a6e74f148c44cf05b24c8ef4e9cd3ef36156",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "llama-network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "kargenia_bot",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.18.1"
        }
    }
]


Are both containers really running in the same network? What does docker network inspect <network> return? You can list all network with docker network ls and then use the network-id of your network for the previous command
